# What does it mean to say that a material "has a finite electrical polarisation even when no external field is applied"?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, material-science, polarization

I am currently studying *Ultrasonic transducers – Materials and design for sensors, actuators and medical applications* by Kentaro Nakamura. In chapter **1.2.1 Ferroelectricity**, the author says the following:

> Piezoelectric materials are a subset of ferroelectric materials and it is therefore useful first to define ferroelectrics (Rosenberg, 1988). These materials are named for the types of properties they share with ferromagnetic materials, not because of an intrinsic link with iron. The key property of a ferroelectric material is that it has a finite electrical polarisation even when no external field is applied. The best example of a ferroelectric material is barium titanate, BaTiO$_3$ (Moulson and Herbert, 2003: 71–82); careful consideration of this material establishes a strong base for understanding other ferroelectric and piezoelectric materials.

I am curious about this part:

> The key property of a ferroelectric material is that it has a finite electrical polarisation even when no external field is applied.

What does it mean to say that a material "has a finite electrical polarisation even when no external field is applied", and how is such a thing possible?

Comment: A molecule may have a dipole moment because of an internal slight separation of charge, right? Now consider a solid comprised of aligned dipole units. Result? A net polarization even without an applied field.

Comment: @JonCuster Wow, that's a great explanation! So it's effectively the overall/net cumulative (charge) effect of many dipole moments of the molecules that comprise the material's (in the case of BaTiO$_3$) crystalline structure?

Comment: There is no net charge though.

Comment: @nasu You're right, its a subtle but important distinction: net polarization is not the same as net charge. So I should have said "So it's effectively the overall/net cumulative (polarization) effect of many dipole moments of the molecules ..." Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: 'How is such a thing possible' - same as magnetism, for some solids/molecules, the lower energy state is the one with net polarization/magnetization.

Comment: It takes more than a molecule with a dipole moment. E.G. $H_2O$ a V-shaped. $O$ is a little 1 and $H$ is a little +. But they face in all different directions. It takes a crystal to orient them all in the same direction. Ice is usually formed from many small crystals, again with different orientations.

Comment: @mmesser314 What does "a little 1" mean? So the the molecular geometry also matters? The example that was given was BaTiO$_3$, which has a crystalline structure.

Comment: Sorry, typo. O is a little -. Geometry matters. + and - atoms are at different ends of the molecule. $CO_2$ is a linear molecule. It wouldn't matter if the center was charged opposite of the ends. There would be no dipole.

Comment: @mmesser314 Understood. Thanks for the clarification.